# How can I remove all annotations from a map using MapKit

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I have tried using the RemoveAnnotation function, but I don't know how to remove them all

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 25.7617,
            longitude: 80.1918
        ),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 100,
            longitudeDelta: 100
        )
    )
    

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    } }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using this extension

```
extension MKMapView {
        
        
        func removeAnnotationAndOverlay(annotation: MKAnnotation) {
            
            removeAnnotation(annotation)
            
            if overlays.count > 0 {
                
                if let overlay = overlays.first {
                    
                    removeOverlay(overlay)
                    
                }
                
            }
           
        }
        
        func removeAllOverlays() {
            
           
            removeOverlays(overlays)
                    
     
            
        }
        
        
        func removeAllAnnotations() {
            
               
            removeAnnotations(annotations)
                
    
        }
        
        func removeAllAnnotationsAndOverlays() {
            
            removeAllOverlays()
            
            removeAllAnnotations()
        }
    }
```

Comment: And where should I call the function, inside the body?

Comment: From your code it's difficult to say. I use MapView as UIViewRepresentable and makeUIView returns actual Map class, in my case class RideMapView: MKMapView, MKMapViewDelegate. Then inside updateUIView i place and remove annotations.